# In PyQt4: How can I influence the behavior of the MDI window?

Tags: qt4, pyqt4, mdi, qwidget, mdichild

Imagine you have a MDI window (QMainWindow - QWorkspace). You open the first QWidget maximized as a subwindow, and you will leave it open. Everything great. Next, you open a second QWidget also as a subwindow, but in this time normal - not maximized. What happens? The second subwindow adapts to the first subwindow and maximizes itself. When I applying the method *resize (0, 0)* in the second subwindow,  and then open the second subwindow, during the first subwindow is already running, then the following happens: The first subwindow adapts to the second subwindow. This is the behavior of a MDI-form.

What I want: None of subwindows should influence each other. When I open maximized the first subwindow, should open the second subwindow normally. Is this possible?

Comment: Is there no way to make that idea?